# Solution for interrupts in linux device drivers

Tags: linux-device-driver, xilinx, pci-e

I am working on `PCIe` communication between `FPGA (ML605)` and `PC`.

The problem I faced is :

From FPGA once i am sending `INTA` `assert packet` then `INTA de-assert packet`, so my expected behavior is my `interrupt  handler` should be invoked once,
But what is happening is that `interrupt handler` is called continuously more than once.

`request_irq function` is as below:

```
        request_irq(gIrq, &XPCIe_IRQHandler, IRQF_SHARED, gDrvrName, gDev)
```

At the ending of `handler`, I have given a return type `IRQ_HANDLED`.

In `cat /proc/interrupts`
my `handler` is `registered` as `IO-APIC fasteoi type`

So can anyone say what may be the problem?

And one more clarification is needed.
When I `insmod` my module for the 2nd time, `interrupt handler` is running without giving an `interrupt`.
In kernel documentation on `PCI`
in `section 3.5 Initialize device registers`
it was written to clear the `pending interrupts` before `request_irq` is called.

So can anybody say how to do that?

my code is

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/pci.h>
#include <linux/interrupt.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
//#include <linux/pci-aspm.h>
//#include <linux/pci_regs.h>

#include <asm/uaccess.h>   /* copy_to_user */

#include "xbmd.h"

// semaphores
enum  {
        SEM_READ,
        SEM_WRITE,
        SEM_WRITEREG,
        SEM_READREG,
        SEM_WAITFOR,
        SEM_DMA,
        NUM_SEMS
      };

//semaphores
struct semaphore gSem[NUM_SEMS];

MODULE_LICENSE("Dual BSD/GPL");

// Defines the Vendor ID.  Must be changed if core generated did not set the Vendor ID to the same value
#define PCI_VENDOR_ID_XILINX      0x10ee

// Defines the Device ID.  Must be changed if core generated did not set the Device ID to the same value
#define PCI_DEVICE_ID_XILINX_PCIE 0x6018 //0x0007

// Defining
#define XBMD_REGISTER_SIZE        (4*8)    // There are eight registers, and each is 4 bytes wide.
#define HAVE_REGION               0x01     // I/O Memory region
#define HAVE_IRQ                  0x02     // Interupt

//Status Flags: 
//       1 = Resouce successfully acquired
//       0 = Resource not acquired.      

#define HAVE_REGION 0x01                    // I/O Memory region
#define HAVE_IRQ    0x02                    // Interupt
#define HAVE_KREG   0x04                    // Kernel registration

int             gDrvrMajor = 241;           // Major number not dynamic.
unsigned int    gStatFlags = 0x00;          // Status flags used for cleanup.
unsigned long   gBaseHdwr;                  // Base register address (Hardware address)
unsigned long   gBaseLen;                   // Base register address Length
void           *gBaseVirt = NULL;           // Base register address (Virtual address, for I/O).
char            gDrvrName[]= "xbmd";        // Name of driver in proc.
struct pci_dev *gDev = NULL;                // PCI device structure.
int             gIrq;                       // IRQ assigned by PCI system.
char           *gBufferUnaligned = NULL;    // Pointer to Unaligned DMA buffer.
char           *gReadBuffer      = NULL;    // Pointer to dword aligned DMA buffer.
char           *gWriteBuffer     = NULL;    // Pointer to dword aligned DMA buffer.
dma_addr_t      gReadHWAddr;
dma_addr_t      gWriteHWAddr;
unsigned long SA_SHIRQ = 0;
unsigned long SA_SAMPLE_RANDOM = 0;

int pos;

// Struct Used for Writing CFG Register.  Holds value and register to be written
typedef struct cfgwrite {
    int reg;
    int value;
} cfgwr;

// Struct Used for Writing BMD Register.  Holds value and register to be written
typedef struct bmdwrite {
    int reg;
    int value;
} bmdwr;
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Prototypes
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

void  XPCIe_IRQHandler (int irq, void *dev_id, struct pt_regs *regs);
u32   XPCIe_ReadReg (u32 dw_offset);
void  XPCIe_WriteReg (u32 dw_offset, u32 val);
void  XPCIe_InitCard (void);
void  XPCIe_InitiatorReset (void);
u32 XPCIe_ReadCfgReg (u32 byte);
u32 XPCIe_WriteCfgReg (u32 byte, u32 value);


int XPCIe_Open(struct inode *inode, struct file *filp)
{
  printk(KERN_INFO"%s: Open: module opened\n",gDrvrName);
  return SUCCESS;
}


int XPCIe_Release(struct inode *inode, struct file *filp)
{
  printk(KERN_INFO"%s: Release: module released\n",gDrvrName);
  return(SUCCESS);
}


ssize_t XPCIe_Write(struct file *filp, const char *buf, size_t count,
                       loff_t *f_pos)
{
  int ret = SUCCESS;
//  memcpy((char *)gWriteBuffer, buf, count);
// printk(KERN_INFO"%s: XPCIe_Write: %d bytes have been written...\n", gDrvrName, count);
  memcpy((char *)gReadBuffer, buf, count);
  printk(KERN_INFO"%s: XPCIe_Write: %d bytes have been written...\n", gDrvrName, count);
  return (ret);
}



ssize_t XPCIe_Read(struct file *filp, char *buf, size_t count, loff_t *f_pos)
{
  memcpy(buf, (char *)gWriteBuffer, count);
  printk(KERN_INFO"%s: XPCIe_Read: %d bytes have been read...\n", gDrvrName, count);
  return (0);
}


int XPCIe_Ioctl(//struct inode *inode, 
                struct file *filp, 
                unsigned int cmd,
                unsigned long arg)
{

  u32 regx;
  int ret = SUCCESS;

  switch (cmd) {

    case INITCARD:                    // Initailizes XBMD application
      XPCIe_InitCard();
      break;
    case INITRST:                     // Resets XBMD applications
      XPCIe_InitiatorReset();
      break;
    case DISPREGS:
      break;
    case RDDCSR:                     // Read: Device Control Status Register
      regx = XPCIe_ReadReg(0);  
      *((u32 *)arg) = regx; 
      break;
    case RDDDMACR:                   // Read: DMA Control Status Register
      regx = XPCIe_ReadReg(1);  
      *((u32 *)arg) = regx; 
      break;
    case RDWDMATLPA:                 // Read: Write DMA TLP Address Register
      regx = XPCIe_ReadReg(2);  
      *((u32 *)arg) = regx; 
      break;
    case RDWDMATLPS:                 // Read: Write DMA TLP Size Register
      regx = XPCIe_ReadReg(3);  
      *((u32 *)arg) = regx; 
      break;
    case RDWDMATLPC:                 // Read: Write DMA TLP Count Register
      regx = XPCIe_ReadReg(4);  
      *((u32 *)arg) = regx; 
      break;
    case RDWDMATLPP:                 // Read: Write DMA TLP Pattern Register
      regx = XPCIe_ReadReg(5);  
      *((u32 *)arg) = regx; 
      break;
    case RDRDMATLPP:                 // Read: Read DMA TLP Pattern Register
      regx = XPCIe_ReadReg(6);  
      *((u32 *)arg) = regx; 
      break;
    case RDRDMATLPA:                 // Read: Read DMA TLP Address Register
      regx = XPCIe_ReadReg(7);  
      *((u32 *)arg) = regx; 
      break;
    case RDRDMATLPS:                 // Read: Read DMA TLP Size Register
      regx = XPCIe_ReadReg(8);  
      *((u32 *)arg) = regx; 
      break;
    case RDRDMATLPC:                 // Read: Read DMA TLP Count Register
      regx = XPCIe_ReadReg(9);  
      *((u32 *)arg) = regx; 
      break;
    case RDWDMAPERF:                 // Read: Write DMA Performance Register
      regx = XPCIe_ReadReg(10);  
      *((u32 *)arg) = regx; 
      break;
    case RDRDMAPERF:                 // Read: Read DMA Performance Register
      regx = XPCIe_ReadReg(11);  
      *((u32 *)arg) = regx; 
      break;
    case RDRDMASTAT:                 // Read: Read DMA Status Register
      regx = XPCIe_ReadReg(12);  
      *((u32 *)arg) = regx; 
      break;
    case RDNRDCOMP:                  // Read: Number of Read Completion w/ Data Register
      regx = XPCIe_ReadReg(13);  
      *((u32 *)arg) = regx; 
      break;
    case RDRCOMPDSIZE:               // Read: Read Completion Size Register
      regx = XPCIe_ReadReg(14);  
      *((u32 *)arg) = regx; 
      break;
    case RDDLWSTAT:                  // Read: Device Link Width Status Register
      regx = XPCIe_ReadReg(15);  
      *((u32 *)arg) = regx; 
      break;
    case RDDLTRSSTAT:                // Read: Device Link Transaction Size Status Register
      regx = XPCIe_ReadReg(16);  
      *((u32 *)arg) = regx; 
      break;
    case RDDMISCCONT:                // Read: Device Miscellaneous Control Register
      regx = XPCIe_ReadReg(17);  
      *((u32 *)arg) = regx; 
      break;
    case RDDMISCONT:                // Read: Device MSI Control
      regx = XPCIe_ReadReg(18);  
      *((u32 *)arg) = regx; 
      break;
    case RDDLNKC:                   // Read: Device Directed Link Change Register
      regx = XPCIe_ReadReg(19);  
      *((u32 *)arg) = regx; 
      break;
    case DFCCTL:                    // Read: Device FC Control Register
      regx = XPCIe_ReadReg(20);  
      *((u32 *)arg) = regx; 
      break;
    case DFCPINFO:                  // Read: Device FC Posted Information
      regx = XPCIe_ReadReg(21);  
      *((u32 *)arg) = regx; 
      break;
    case DFCNPINFO:                 // Read: Device FC Non Posted Information
      regx = XPCIe_ReadReg(22);  
      *((u32 *)arg) = regx; 
      break;
    case DFCINFO:                  // Read: Device FC Completion Information
      regx = XPCIe_ReadReg(23);  
      *((u32 *)arg) = regx; 
      break;
    case WRDDMACR:                 // Write: DMA Control Status Register
      XPCIe_WriteReg(1, arg);
      break;
    case WRWDMATLPS:               // Write: Write DMA TLP Size Register
      XPCIe_WriteReg(3, arg);
      break;
    case WRWDMATLPC:               // Write: Write DMA TLP Count Register
      XPCIe_WriteReg(4, arg);
      break;
    case WRWDMATLPP:               // Write: Write DMA TLP Pattern Register
      XPCIe_WriteReg(5, arg);
      break;
    case WRRDMATLPS:               // Write: Read DMA TLP Size Register
      XPCIe_WriteReg(8, arg);
      break;
    case WRRDMATLPC:               // Write: Read DMA TLP Count Register
      XPCIe_WriteReg(9, arg);
      break;
    case WRRDMATLPP:               // Write: Read DMA TLP Pattern Register
      XPCIe_WriteReg(6, arg);
      break;
    case WRDMISCCONT:              // Write: Device Miscellaneous Control Register
      XPCIe_WriteReg(18, arg);
      break;
    case WRDDLNKC:                 // Write: Device Directed Link Change Register
      XPCIe_WriteReg(19, arg);
      break;
    case RDBMDREG:                 // Read: Any XBMD Reg.  Added generic functionality so all register can be read
      regx = XPCIe_ReadReg(*(u32 *)arg);  
      *((u32 *)arg) = regx; 
      break; 
    case RDCFGREG:                 // Read: Any CFG Reg.  Added generic functionality so all register can be read
      regx = XPCIe_ReadCfgReg(*(u32 *)arg);  
      *((u32 *)arg) = regx; 
      break;
   case WRBMDREG:                 // Write: Any BMD Reg.  Added generic functionality so all register can be read
        XPCIe_WriteReg((*(bmdwr *)arg).reg,(*(bmdwr *)arg).value);
    printk(KERN_WARNING"%d: Write Register.\n", (*(bmdwr *)arg).reg);
    printk(KERN_WARNING"%d: Write Value\n", (*(bmdwr *)arg).value);
    break;
   case WRCFGREG:                 // Write: Any CFG Reg.  Added generic functionality so all register can be read
        regx = XPCIe_WriteCfgReg((*(cfgwr *)arg).reg,(*(cfgwr *)arg).value);
    printk(KERN_WARNING"%d: Write Register.\n", (*(cfgwr *)arg).reg);
    printk(KERN_WARNING"%d: Write Value\n", (*(cfgwr *)arg).value);
    break;
    default:
      break;
  }

  return ret;
}


// Aliasing write, read, ioctl, etc...
struct file_operations XPCIe_Intf = {
    read:       XPCIe_Read,
    write:      XPCIe_Write,
    unlocked_ioctl:      XPCIe_Ioctl,
    open:       XPCIe_Open,
    release:    XPCIe_Release,
};


static int XPCIe_init(void)
{
  // Find the Xilinx EP device.  The device is found by matching device and vendor ID's which is defined
  // at the top of this file.  Be default, the driver will look for 10EE & 0007.  If the core is generated 
  // with other settings, the defines at the top must be changed or the driver will not load
  gDev = pci_get_device (PCI_VENDOR_ID_XILINX, PCI_DEVICE_ID_XILINX_PCIE, gDev); 
// gDev = pci_find_device (PCI_VENDOR_ID_XILINX, PCI_DEVICE_ID_XILINX_PCIE, gDev);
  if (NULL == gDev) {

    // If a matching device or vendor ID is not found, return failure and update kernel log. 
    // NOTE: In fedora systems, the kernel log is located at: /var/log/messages
    printk(KERN_WARNING"%s: Init: Hardware not found.\n", gDrvrName);
    return (CRIT_ERR);
  }

  // Get Base Address of registers from pci structure. Should come from pci_dev
  // structure, but that element seems to be missing on the development system.
  gBaseHdwr = pci_resource_start (gDev, 0);

  if (0 > gBaseHdwr) {
    printk(KERN_WARNING"%s: Init: Base Address not set.\n", gDrvrName);
    return (CRIT_ERR);
  } 

  // Print Base Address to kernel log
  printk(KERN_INFO"%s: Init: Base hw val %X\n", gDrvrName, (unsigned int)gBaseHdwr);

  // Get the Base Address Length
  gBaseLen = pci_resource_len (gDev, 0);

  // Print the Base Address Length to Kernel Log
  printk(KERN_INFO"%s: Init: Base hw len %d\n", gDrvrName, (unsigned int)gBaseLen);

  // Remap the I/O register block so that it can be safely accessed.
  // I/O register block starts at gBaseHdwr and is 32 bytes long.
  // It is cast to char because that is the way Linus does it.
  // Reference "/usr/src/Linux-2.4/Documentation/IO-mapping.txt".
  gBaseVirt = ioremap(gBaseHdwr, gBaseLen);
  if (!gBaseVirt) {
    printk(KERN_WARNING"%s: Init: Could not remap memory.\n", gDrvrName);
    return (CRIT_ERR);
  } 

  // Print out the aquired virtual base addresss
  printk(KERN_INFO"%s: Init: Virt HW address %X\n", gDrvrName, (unsigned int)gBaseVirt);

  // Get IRQ from pci_dev structure. It may have been remapped by the kernel,
  // and this value will be the correct one.
  gIrq = gDev->irq;
  printk(KERN_INFO"%s: Init: Device IRQ: %X\n",gDrvrName, gIrq);


  //---START: Initialize Hardware

  // Check the memory region to see if it is in use
  if (0 > check_mem_region(gBaseHdwr, XBMD_REGISTER_SIZE)) {
    printk(KERN_WARNING"%s: Init: Memory in use.\n", gDrvrName);
    return (CRIT_ERR);
  }

  // Try to gain exclusive control of memory for demo hardware.
  request_mem_region(gBaseHdwr, XBMD_REGISTER_SIZE, "3GIO_Demo_Drv");
  // Update flags
  gStatFlags = gStatFlags | HAVE_REGION;

  printk(KERN_INFO"%s: Init: Initialize Hardware Done..\n",gDrvrName);

  // Request IRQ from OS.
  // In past architectures, the SHARED and SAMPLE_RANDOM flags were called: SA_SHIRQ and SA_SAMPLE_RANDOM
  // respectively.  In older Fedora core installations, the request arguments may need to be reverted back.
  // SA_SHIRQ | SA_SAMPLE_RANDOM
  printk(KERN_INFO"%s: ISR Setup..\n", gDrvrName);
   if (0 > request_irq(gIrq, (irq_handler_t)XPCIe_IRQHandler, IRQF_SHARED, gDrvrName, gDev)) {
// if (0 > request_irq(gIrq, &XPCIe_IRQHandler, IRQF_SHARED | IRQF_SAMPLE_RANDOM, gDrvrName, gDev)) {
    printk(KERN_WARNING"%s: Init: Unable to allocate IRQ",gDrvrName);
    return (CRIT_ERR);
  }
  // Update flags stating IRQ was successfully obtained
  gStatFlags = gStatFlags | HAVE_IRQ;

  // Bus Master Enable
  if (0 > pci_enable_device(gDev)) {
    printk(KERN_WARNING"%s: Init: Device not enabled.\n", gDrvrName);
    return (CRIT_ERR);
  }

  //--- END: Initialize Hardware

  //--- START: Allocate Buffers

  // Allocate the read buffer with size BUF_SIZE and return the starting address
  gReadBuffer = pci_alloc_consistent(gDev, BUF_SIZE, &gReadHWAddr);
  if (NULL == gReadBuffer) {
    printk(KERN_CRIT"%s: Init: Unable to allocate gBuffer.\n",gDrvrName);
    return (CRIT_ERR);
  }
  // Print Read buffer size and address to kernel log
  printk(KERN_INFO"%s: Read Buffer Allocation: %X->%X\n", gDrvrName, (unsigned int)gReadBuffer, (unsigned int)gReadHWAddr);

  // Allocate the write buffer with size BUF_SIZE and return the starting address
  gWriteBuffer = pci_alloc_consistent(gDev, BUF_SIZE, &gWriteHWAddr);
  if (NULL == gWriteBuffer) {
    printk(KERN_CRIT"%s: Init: Unable to allocate gBuffer.\n",gDrvrName);
    return (CRIT_ERR);
  }
  // Print Write buffer size and address to kernel log  
  printk(KERN_INFO"%s: Write Buffer Allocation: %X->%X\n", gDrvrName, (unsigned int)gWriteBuffer, (unsigned int)gWriteHWAddr);

  //--- END: Allocate Buffers

  //--- START: Register Driver

  // Register with the kernel as a character device.
  if (0 > register_chrdev(gDrvrMajor, gDrvrName, &XPCIe_Intf)) {
    printk(KERN_WARNING"%s: Init: will not register\n", gDrvrName);
    return (CRIT_ERR);
  }
  printk(KERN_INFO"%s: Init: module registered\n", gDrvrName);
  gStatFlags = gStatFlags | HAVE_KREG;

  //--- END: Register Driver

  // The driver is now successfully loaded.  All HW is initialized, IRQ's assigned, and buffers allocated
  printk("%s driver is loaded\n", gDrvrName);


  // Initializing card registers
  XPCIe_InitCard();

  return 0;
}

//--- XPCIe_InitiatorReset(): Resets the XBMD reference design
//--- Arguments: None
//--- Return Value: None
//--- Detailed Description: Writes a 1 to the DCSR register which resets the XBMD design
void XPCIe_InitiatorReset()
{
  XPCIe_WriteReg(0, 1);                   // Write: DCSR (offset 0) with value of 1 (Reset Device)
  XPCIe_WriteReg(0, 0);                   // Write: DCSR (offset 0) with value of 0 (Make Active)
}


//--- XPCIe_InitCard(): Initializes XBMD descriptor registers to default values
//--- Arguments: None
//--- Return Value: None
//--- Detailed Description: 1) Resets device
//---                       2) Writes specific values into the XBMD registers inside the EP 
void XPCIe_InitCard()
{

  XPCIe_WriteReg(0, 1);                   // Write: DCSR (offset 0) with value of 1 (Reset Device)
  XPCIe_WriteReg(0, 0);                   // Write: DCSR (offset 0) with value of 0 (Make Active)

  XPCIe_WriteReg(2, gWriteHWAddr);        // Write: Write DMA TLP Address register with starting address
  XPCIe_WriteReg(3, 0x20);                // Write: Write DMA TLP Size register with default value (32dwords)
  XPCIe_WriteReg(4, 0x2000);              // Write: Write DMA TLP Count register with default value (2000)
  XPCIe_WriteReg(5, 0x00000000);          // Write: Write DMA TLP Pattern register with default value (0x0)

  XPCIe_WriteReg(6, 0xfeedbeef);          // Write: Read DMA Expected Data Pattern with default value (feedbeef)
  XPCIe_WriteReg(7, gReadHWAddr);         // Write: Read DMA TLP Address register with starting address.
  XPCIe_WriteReg(8, 0x20);                // Write: Read DMA TLP Size register with default value (32dwords)
  XPCIe_WriteReg(9, 0x2000);              // Write: Read DMA TLP Count register with default value (2000)
}

//--- XPCIe_exit(): Performs any cleanup required before releasing the device
//--- Arguments: None
//--- Return Value: None
//--- Detailed Description: Performs all cleanup functions required before releasing device
static void XPCIe_exit(void)
{
    printk("N_TEST:in exit\n");
  // Check if we have a memory region and free it
  if (gStatFlags & HAVE_REGION) {
     (void) release_mem_region(gBaseHdwr, XBMD_REGISTER_SIZE);}
    printk("N_TEST:rel reg cmp\n");
    // Check if we have an IRQ and free it
    if (gStatFlags & HAVE_IRQ) {
        (void) free_irq(gIrq, gDev);
    }
    printk("N_TEST:free irq cmp\n");
    // Free Write and Read buffers allocated to use
//    if (NULL != gReadBuffer)
//        (void) kfree(gReadBuffer);
//    if (NULL != gWriteBuffer)
//        (void) kfree(gWriteBuffer);
//  printk("N_TEST:free buff cmp\n");
    // Free memory allocated to our Endpoint
    pci_free_consistent(gDev, BUF_SIZE, gReadBuffer, gReadHWAddr);
    pci_free_consistent(gDev, BUF_SIZE, gWriteBuffer, gWriteHWAddr);
    printk("N_TEST:free consitent mem\n");
    gReadBuffer = NULL;
    gWriteBuffer = NULL;

    // Free up memory pointed to by virtual address
    if (gBaseVirt != NULL) {
        iounmap(gBaseVirt);
     }
    printk("N_TEST:io unmap cmp\n");   
    gBaseVirt = NULL;

    // Unregister Device Driver
    if (gStatFlags & HAVE_KREG) {
      unregister_chrdev(gDrvrMajor, gDrvrName);
    }
    printk("N_TEST:un reg chr dev cmp\n");
    gStatFlags = 0;

    // Update Kernel log stating driver is unloaded
    printk(KERN_ALERT"%s driver is unloaded\n", gDrvrName);
}

// Driver Entry Point
module_init(XPCIe_init);

// Driver Exit Point
module_exit(XPCIe_exit);
```

static irq_return_t XPCIe_IRQHandler(int irq, void *dev_id, struct pt_regs *regs)
    {
      u32 i, regx;

```
  printk(KERN_WARNING"%s: Interrupt Handler Start ..",gDrvrName);

  for (i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
     regx = XPCIe_ReadReg(i);
     printk(KERN_WARNING"%s : REG<%d> : 0x%X\n", gDrvrName, i, regx);
  }

  printk(KERN_WARNING"%s Interrupt Handler End ..\n", gDrvrName);
```

return IRQ_HANDLED;
 }

```
u32 XPCIe_ReadReg (u32 dw_offset)
{
        u32 ret = 0;
        //u32 reg_addr = (u32)(gBaseVirt + (4 * dw_offset));
        //ret = readl(reg_addr);  
        ret = readl(gBaseVirt + (4 * dw_offset));  

        return ret; 
}

void XPCIe_WriteReg (u32 dw_offset, u32 val)
{printk("Nag:offset=%d\tval=%x\n",dw_offset,val);
        //u32 reg_addr = (u32)(gBaseVirt + (4 * dw_offset));
        writel(val, (gBaseVirt + (4 * dw_offset)));
}

ssize_t* XPCIe_ReadMem(char *buf, size_t count)
{

    int ret = 0;
    dma_addr_t dma_addr;

    //make sure passed in buffer is large enough
    if ( count < BUF_SIZE )  {
      printk("%s: XPCIe_Read: passed in buffer too small.\n", gDrvrName);
      ret = -1;
      goto exit;
    }

    down(&gSem[SEM_DMA]);

    // pci_map_single return the physical address corresponding to 
    // the virtual address passed to it as the 2nd parameter

    dma_addr = pci_map_single(gDev, gReadBuffer, BUF_SIZE, PCI_DMA_FROMDEVICE);
    if ( 0 == dma_addr )  {
        printk("%s: XPCIe_Read: Map error.\n",gDrvrName);
        ret = -1;
        goto exit;
    }

    // Now pass the physical address to the device hardware. This is now
    // the destination physical address for the DMA and hence the to be
    // put on Memory Transactions

    // Do DMA transfer here....

    printk("%s: XPCIe_Read: ReadBuf Virt Addr = %x Phy Addr = %x.\n", 
            gDrvrName, (unsigned int)gReadBuffer, (unsigned int)dma_addr);

    // Unmap the DMA buffer so it is safe for normal access again.
    pci_unmap_single(gDev, dma_addr, BUF_SIZE, PCI_DMA_FROMDEVICE);

    up(&gSem[SEM_DMA]);

    // Now it is safe to copy the data to user space.
    if ( copy_to_user(buf, gReadBuffer, BUF_SIZE) )  {
        ret = -1;
        printk("%s: XPCIe_Read: Failed copy to user.\n",gDrvrName);
        goto exit;
    }
    exit:
      return ret;
}

ssize_t XPCIe_WriteMem(const char *buf, size_t count) {
    int ret = 0;
    dma_addr_t dma_addr;

    if ( (count % 4) != 0 )  {
       printk("%s: XPCIe_Write: Buffer length not dword aligned.\n",gDrvrName);
       ret = -1;
       goto exit;
    }

    // Now it is safe to copy the data from user space.
    if ( copy_from_user(gWriteBuffer, buf, count) )  {
        ret = -1;
        printk("%s: XPCIe_Write: Failed copy to user.\n",gDrvrName);
        goto exit;
    }

    //set DMA semaphore if in loopback
    down(&gSem[SEM_DMA]);

    // pci_map_single return the physical address corresponding to 
    // the virtual address passed to it as the 2nd parameter

    dma_addr = pci_map_single(gDev, gWriteBuffer, BUF_SIZE, PCI_DMA_FROMDEVICE);
    if ( 0 == dma_addr )  {
        printk("%s: XPCIe_Write: Map error.\n",gDrvrName);
        ret = -1;
        goto exit;
    }

    // Now pass the physical address to the device hardware. This is now
    // the source physical address for the DMA and hence the to be
    // put on Memory Transactions

    // Do DMA transfer here....

    printk("%s: XPCIe_Write: WriteBuf Virt Addr = %x Phy Addr = %x.\n",  
           gDrvrName, (unsigned int)gReadBuffer, (unsigned int)dma_addr);

    // Unmap the DMA buffer so it is safe for normal access again.
    pci_unmap_single(gDev, dma_addr, BUF_SIZE, PCI_DMA_FROMDEVICE);

    up(&gSem[SEM_DMA]);

    exit:
      return (ret);
}

u32 XPCIe_ReadCfgReg (u32 byte) {
   u32 pciReg;
   if (pci_read_config_dword(gDev, byte, &pciReg) < 0) {
        printk("%s: XPCIe_ReadCfgReg: Reading PCI interface failed.",gDrvrName);
        return (-1);
   }
   return (pciReg);
}

u32 XPCIe_WriteCfgReg (u32 byte, u32 val) {
   if (pci_write_config_dword(gDev, byte, val) < 0) {
        printk("%s: XPCIe_Read Device Control: Reading PCI interface failed.",gDrvrName);
        return (-1);
   }
   return 1;
}
```

Comment: To start `debugging` with, can you try it without the `IRQF_SHARED` flag? This would ensure that other `devices` are not sharing `irq` with your `device`

Comment: In addition to @SachinMokashi reccomendation. What is your INTA assertition length ? Normally the FPGA should assert INTA, the interrupt handler access the FPGA to deassert it then return.

Comment: Show entire `->probe()` function here. It's hard to diagnose by one line.

Comment: Iam using legacy clear mode of operation, means FPGA will send assert packet and next deassert packet....I have tried to reset registers from PC using interrupt handler...but it has not worked....@claudio

Comment: Code is ugliest I ever see! But to the topic: your IRQ handler shall return handle code, in your case it returns whoever whatever knows, I suspect 0, which mean IRQ_NONE, which obviously means no IRQ were handled.

Comment: I have tried without IRQF_SHARED flag, but because of flags mismatch request_irq failes. As PCIe is a shared irq service, I have to compulsorily use that flag. @SachinMokashi

Comment: Why what happened...any wrong in my code.. @0andriy

Comment: Now i have changed my irq handler to `static irq_handler_t my_IRQHandler(int irq, void *dev_id, struct pt_regs *regs)
{
  u32 i, regx;
  printk(KERN_WARNING"%s:11 Interrupt Handler Start ..\n",gDrvrName);
  

InitCard();

  printk(KERN_WARNING"%s:22 Interrupt Handler End ..\n", gDrvrName);

printk(KERN_WARNING "NAG INT HAND SUCCESS\n");
 return (irq_handler_t)IRQ_HANDLED;` @0andriy